# Implementing Tribool with int8_t

Tags: c++

For digital electronic circuit simulation, i wanted to implement Three states. i.e **High**, **Low** and **Undefined** in C++.

I saw `Boost::tribool`, and they implement it using `enum`

Now for conserving some memory i have implemented it using 1 Byte Int

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
typedef __int8 State;
#elif
typedef int8_t State;
#endif

const State kLow = 0;
const State kHigh = 1;
const State kUndefined = 2;
```

1. Do you see any potential problem with it?
2. And why would one *waste* 4 bytes instead of a single byte for 3 values only
3. Do you have a still better way?

Comment: That's an 8-bit int, not a 1-byte int.

Comment: Of course, but I was more concerned about memory usage, that's why byte. Ha, I would have loved to do this in 2 bits instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using enumerations. As this is December 2011, I would imagine your compiler supports an explicit underlying type on enumerations (GCC supported this since 4.4 and Visual C++ now supports it in 11.0). As a side note, `<cstdint>` is supported by visual c++ now (as of 10.0).

As an addenum to traditional c-style enumerations:

```
enum state : std::int8_t {
    S_UNKNWON,
    S_HIGH,
    S_LOW
};
```

Or adding scope to the enumeration's memebers (avoid polluting global scope):

```
enum class state : std::int8_t {
    unknown,
    high,
    low
};

state status = state::unknown;
```

Of course, after looking at `boost::tribool`, I would recommend that over anything -- unless you really need to ensure that `state` is exactly 1 byte.

Comment: +1 for informing about cstdint. no more #ifdef required. And yeah i wanted some savings, so enum state : int8_t solved the problem, with type safety!

Answer (score 5):

The **main** reason there is no accidental conversion (type safety is one of the keys to using C++ correctly).

```
enum Tri { Yes, No, Maybe };

int main()
{
    Tri     y   = Yes;
    y= 1;   // Fails to compile.
}
```

Secondly you are using three bytes to hold the different states here

```
const State kLow = 0;
const State kHigh = 1;
const State kUndefined = 2;
```

With an enum there is no space taken up (though potentially the above may be optimized out).

C++11 also allows you to specify the size of an enum:

```
enum class Tri : char { Yes, No, Maybe };
//               ^^^^  Uses a char sized object
```

> Do you see any potential problem with it?

Yes. Not type safe

> And why would one waste 4 bytes instead of a single byte for 3 values only

Why not. Does it really matter in any modern PC.
OK for embedded systems maybe (but you obviously are using WINDOWS)

> Do you have a still better way?

Yes. Use enum in C++11

Comment: I got a kick out of pushing you over the 5K border ^^

Comment: every time one reminds me of good habit (here not ditching enum) i +1 :)